# Find the interior points for the following sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the interior points for the following sets:
>
> 1. The set $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$
> 2. The set $B = \{(x,y): 0 < x+y \leq 1 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

**My Attempt:**

1. $A^0= \emptyset$, since there is no point $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ within $\mathbb{R}$ for which we can find a $r$-neighnorhood such that the interior contains only rationals.
2. $B^0= \{(x,y): 0 < x+y <1 \}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Are these correct?

Comment: Yes, your answers are correct.

Comment: I didn't see your answers at first. Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Crostul - thank you! :). Cant the same reasoning of Q1 be used to show the interior points of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is also the empty set?

Comment: Yes. In particular, if $A \subseteq B$, then $A^0 \subseteq B^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed answers are correct. To make your claims rigorous and complete, for the first case you need to show for example that in between any two distinct real numbers there is an irrational number, and for the second case you need to show that if $0 < x + y < 1$ then $(x,y)$ is an interior point of the set (according to the usual definition of interior points for sets in ${\mathbb R}^d$), and if $x + y = 1$ then $(x,y)$ is not an interior point (in fact, it is on the boundary of the set).